# How does repeating the payload(data) reduce latency in web socket?

Tags: javascript, sockets, http, websocket, frames

I am doing a demo on web sockets - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets.

I know that the definition of latency is the amount of time for "it takes for a packet of data to get from one designated point to another." http://www.linfo.org/latency.html

This simple simply consists of sending a basic message, in my case "jasmine", to the server via a web socket. The article on treehouse discussed how "Data is transferred through a WebSocket as messages, each of which consists of one or more frames containing the data you are sending (the payload). Using this frame-based messaging system helps to reduce the amount of non-payload data that is transferred, leading to significant reductions in latency."

My question is whenever i send a get request to the web socket, why do I see two frames in the GET request that consist of my data, "jasmine", not just one? I don't see how that would decrease latency. This is what I mean, when I go to inspect element tool - > network, this is what i see in the header,
[image]

and what I see in the frames tab,
[image]

How does having two frames consisting of the payload(the data) reduce latency?

Comment: Might one of them be the _response_ from the echo host?

Comment: Yeah that would make sense but the header says that it is a GET request so I am assuming all the frames are apart of the GET request

Answer (score 1):

@Willian Price is right (see comments).

When the connection is UPGRADEd to WebSocket protocol, it is no longer HTTP. You can see the initial Handshake request (HTTP GET), but after that, server responds 101 SWITCHING PROTOCOLS and that is for HTTP - after this, there is a new, persistent TCP connection which uses WebSocket protocol ([RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)) to communicate and there is no longer any connection about "request" and "response" - it is message based and any side can send a message.

What you see indeed is one message which you sent and the other replied from the server. (that what [echo.websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) does - ECHOes the message back to the client).

Comment: but both frames are apart of my initial GET request?

Comment: As I mentioned, WebSocket protocol does not use HTTP - no frame can be sent with initial HTTP request ('GET'; 'Upgrade Request' in WebSocket terminology).